# System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve project 'ef' in EF7 at asp.net mvc 6 in data migration

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I want to create the database using Data Migration in Entity Framework 7 in asp.net MVC 6. But I'm facing following problems:

> C:\Users\Elpic04\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\ContosoBooks\src\ContosoBooks>dnx ef . migration add
>   Initial
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve project 'ef' from
>   C:\Users\Elpic04\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\ContosoBooks\src\ContosoBooks\ef    at
>   Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.ApplicationHostContext..ctor(IServiceProvider
>   serviceProvider, String projectDirectory, String packagesDirectory,
>   String configuration, FrameworkName targetFramework, ICache cache,
>   ICacheContextAccessor cacheContextAccessor,
>   INamedCacheDependencyProvider namedCacheDependencyProvider,
>   IAssemblyLoadContextFactory loadContextFactory, Boolean
>   skipLockFileValidation)    at
>   Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.DefaultHost.Initialize(DefaultHostOptions
>   options, IServiceProvider hostServices)    at
>   Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.DefaultHost..ctor(DefaultHostOptions
>   options, IServiceProvider hostServices)    at
>   Microsoft.Framework.ApplicationHost.Program.Main(String[] args)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Common.EntryPointExecutor.Execute(Assembly
>   assembly, String[] args, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)    at
>   dnx.host.Bootstrapper.RunAsync(List`1 args, IRuntimeEnvironment env)
>   at dnx.host.RuntimeBootstrapper.ExecuteAsync(String[] args)    at
>   dnx.host.RuntimeBootstrapper.Execute(String[] args)

Answer (score 0):

What .net framework are you using?

According to this document:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2015/07/20/entity-framework-and-visual-studio-2015-rtm.aspx

> Full .NET applications (Console, WPF, WinForms, and ASP.NET 4) that target .NET 4.5.1 or later.

Try upgrading your framework version?